# Office switch license from personal to office365

Tags: microsoft-office, license, office365

I installed office 2016 on my PC using a personal license (normal, no subscription). Now I've got an Office 365 license/account from my employer. Is there a way to just switch the license/add the account somewhere? The account is the same (by credentials) as the one I use to connect to exchange server.

I don't want to reinstall office.

Comment: It's as simple as switching the account from your personal account to your work account then disconnect your personal account.  If you don't disconnect your personal account from within office your perpetual license will still be used.  If that doesn't work then your only other solution is to uninstall Office 2016 and then install Office 365.

Comment: the former office was not bound to any account. for most apps it worked to just add the new account but one drive didn't worked. now i uninstalled both office completely and reinstalled.

Comment: You would have to add the Work account within OneDrive separately as it's not part of the Office suite